# how to remove linux based program in OSX

Tags: macos, shell, valgrind

I have installed Valgrind on my Mac; but it didn’t work because the instructions I followed were based on a Linux environment:

1. cd into the source directory.
2. Run ./autogen.sh to setup the environment (you need the standard
    autoconf tools to do so).
3. Run ./configure, with some options if you wish.  The only interesting
    one is the usual --prefix=/where/you/want/it/installed.
4. Run "make".
5. Run "make install", possibly as root if the destination permissions
    require that.

when I tried `valgrind ls -l` I got:

```
valgrind: Unknown/uninstalled VG_PLATFORM 'amd64-darwin'
```

So, I tried via Homebrew:

```
brew install valgrind
```

It successfully ran; but when I tried the valgrind command again, the former installation overrided my shell command.

In this situation, how can I properly remove the former Valgrind installation?

Comment: What did you set the interesting prefix to?

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems to be set cd /usr/local as default.

Comment: The title is incorrect. Your `valgrind` is not Linux based (just manually built and poorly configured)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments by @bfontaine, it may just be a hashing issue, and readily solved by running:

```
hash -r
```

As further suggested in the comments by @Petesh, your initial installation of the *"Linux"* package may have introduced a `/usr/local/bin/valgrind`, which **homebrew** would not replace. To see if that is the case, run:

```
brew doctor
```

and see if **homebrew**'s `valgrind` is unlinked. If it is, follow the good doctor's recommendation and remove the one you incorrectly installed and then relink the **homebrew** version:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/valgrind
brew link valgrind
```

Otherwise, the first thing to do is run:

```
type valgrind
```

That will tell you what actually gets run when you run `valgrind`.

The next thing is to know that **homebrew** installs everything in `/usr/local/bin`, so if the first command above doesn't tell you `/usr/local/bin/valgrind` the problem is either that:

- `valgrind` is superseded by a function or alias - in which case delete the alias or function, or
- that your PATH has been set to include something before `/usr/local/bin` that contains `valgrind`. So you need to run:

  echo $PATH

and check if you have something like `/usr/local/my/funky/bin` ahead of `/usr/local/bin` - which is the correct one you should have.

If your PATH is wrong, you can set it with a command something like this:

```
export PATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
```

although the exact contents will depend on what you had there before.

Once everything works, if it involved changing your PATH, you should make sure that the PATH is always set that way in your login profile, which may be in one of the following files:

```
$HOME/.profile
$HOME/.bash_profile
$HOME/.bash_login
```

Comment: It’s probably an issue with Bash’s command caching too: `hash -r` or restarting a session will fix it.

Comment: @marksetchell I tried type valgrind . 
valgrind is /usr/local/bin/valgrind
and I checked my $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
I think It is same problem with homebrew install. not bash command parsing problem.
May be I have to solve the problem below.
**valgrind: Unknown/uninstalled VG_PLATFORM 'amd64-darwin'**
thank you

Comment: brew will avoid replacing manually installed binaries, so, for example, it won't override `/usr/local/bin/valgrind` if there's a real file there - use `brew doctor` to find unexpected files and remove them. Then you can use `brew link valgrind` to try to get the correct links in place

Comment: @Petesh **I tried brew doctor**

`Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run brew link on these:
  valgrind`


**so I tried brew link --overwrite valgrind**


`Linking /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.13.0... 
Error: Could not symlink include/valgrind/callgrind.h
/usr/local/include/valgrind is not writable.`

**May be I have to remove mannually installed valgrind files. Let's go back to my original question**

Comment: Please don't put code or output in comments section - instead, please click `edit` under original question and add the information in there. Thank you.

Comment: Please try `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/valgrind`

Comment: It works well! thanks. the correct answer for my original question was `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/valgrind` and `brew link valgrind`